# Refactor Javascript class as a Module

Tags: javascript, class, module

i'm reading some javascript books and doing some excercises and i'm a little stuck while doing the following:
Refactor Movie class as a Module keeping your previous code for reference.

My previous code is this:

```
function Movie(){
    this.attributes = {
        title : '',
        duration : '',
        director : '',
        actor : []
    }
}

Movie.prototype.set= function(attr , value){
    this.attributes[attr] = value;
}

Movie.prototype.get = function(){
    console.log(this.attributes.title);
    return this.attributes.title;
}

Movie.prototype.play = function (){
    console.log ('Playing '+this.attributes['title']+'...');
}

Movie.prototype.stop= function(){
    console.log ('Stopped '+this.attributes['title']+'...');
}
```

I don't know what should i do to refactor it. I read a lot about that but i don't know how to then use it as a class (or if that's possible) for example now i can create more movies by doing var titanic = new Movie() , if i make a module i don't how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "module"? That's a bit vague.

Comment: Your code is a perfectly fine module. It does export a single `Movie` symbol.

Comment: Or: what does the book/exercise mean by "module"? Maybe you could link or cite it, or at least mention the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor it using these [guides](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

```
var Movie = function () {

  var model = {
    attributes : {
        title : '',
        duration : '',
        director : '',
        actor : []
        }
    };

    model.set = function (attr , value) {
        model.attributes[attr] = value;
    }

    model.get  = function () {
        return model.attributes;
    }

    model.play = function (){
        console.log ('Playing '+this.attributes['title']+'...');
    }

    model.stop= function(){
        console.log ('Stopped '+this.attributes['title']+'...');
    }

    return model;
});
```

and use it like this

```
var movie1 = new Movie();
var movie2 = new Movie();
```

Comment: You _can,_ but why would you?

Comment: By my opinion this way code is cleaner. But yes, that is my opinion, and its not something that needs to be followed.

Comment: I was trying to prompt you to add more explanation to the answer. Note that moving the functions into the constructor with `this.play = function() {}` would effectively do the same thing just as cleanly, but be slightly shorter (no need then for the `return`). Except that of course either way removes the advantage of having the functions on the prototype...

Comment: Is it okay to do model.stop? Instead of model.prototype.stop, i read that it was better to use prototype.